# Why decouple applications where there is a fast producer and slow consumer? What happens?

Tags: amazon-sqs, producer-consumer

I'm reading about SQS and message queues and I'm wondering what happens when there is a fast producer and slow consumer. What happens? Where is the message buildup stored? Is it on the memory stack and eventually a stack overflow happens and the server crashes? Is that the problem that memory is used as queue which is finite?

Answer (score 0):

If you continuously consume messages more slowly than they are produced, typically messages in SQS (or whichever other message system you may choose to use) will expire and be lost. Slow consumer can cause memory problems if you have a producer and consumer in the same in-memory streams, and in that case you may run out of memory and crash, but that is less typical in a message based architecture. More commonly messages will be stored on disk, but there is usually still a finite retention period.

[Edit]

If you use an in memory *unbounded* queue, you can run into issues, take the following example:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue

class SlowConsumer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue: Queue):
        self.queue = queue
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            v = self.queue.get()
            print(f"Processing #{v}")
            time.sleep(1)

q = Queue()
c = SlowConsumer(q)
c.start()

i=0
while True:
    q.put(i)
    i+=1
    time.sleep(.1)
```

The consumer will always be falling further and further behind the producer. In the end, the process will exhaust available memory. This is a pathalogical case which should be avoided -- generally by using a bounded queue. Note: effectively the same problem can exist with external queues that support limitless retention, such as Kafka, but we won't run out of memory, we will run out of disk. For on disk queues, it is also best to set a retention period, if a sensible one exists.

Comment: What is the mechanism in which you run out of memory? Can you go into more detail about how that happens when the producer an consumer are in the smae application without a message queue?

Comment: How do you propose your producer and consumer communicate data without a message queue?

Comment: Edited to add in memory example

Comment: If they were inside the same monolith... wouldn't the "producer" communicate with the "consumer" just via function calls? Like `callConsumer(message)`?

Comment: Not necessarily. A message queue like this is often the way multiple threads communicate when concurrency is required in-process.